# Formatting issue with Terraform to create service bus topics

Tags: terraform, terraform-provider-azure, azure-servicebus-topics

I'm trying to add a new service bus topic to the existing service bus. Currently the service bus has only 1 topic and I'm trying to add one more to the existing resource. When I'm trying to do this I'm getting a terraform format error.

##[error]Terraform command 'fmt' failed with exit code '3'.

Current Terrform variable,

```
variable "servicebus_topics" {
type = list(object({
  topic_name                              = string
  default_message_ttl                     = optional(string)
  max_size_in_megabytes                   = optional(number)
  requires_duplicate_detection            = optional(bool)
  duplicate_detection_history_time_window = optional(string)
  enable_batched_operations               = optional(bool)
  support_ordering                        = optional(bool)
  auto_delete_on_idle                     = optional(string)
  enable_partitioning                     = optional(bool)
  enable_express                          = optional(bool)
}))
description = "Topic details"
default = [{
  topic_name = "topic1"
}]
}
```

With the above variable value I'm not facing any issue. But When I try to add a new topic "topic2" to the existing variable value under the default property. I'm getting the format failed error as below,

```
variable "servicebus_topics" {
type = list(object({
  topic_name                              = string
  default_message_ttl                     = optional(string)
  max_size_in_megabytes                   = optional(number)
  requires_duplicate_detection            = optional(bool)
  duplicate_detection_history_time_window = optional(string)
  enable_batched_operations               = optional(bool)
  support_ordering                        = optional(bool)
  auto_delete_on_idle                     = optional(string)
  enable_partitioning                     = optional(bool)
  enable_express                          = optional(bool)
}))
description = "Topic details"
default = [{
  topic_name = "topic1"
},
{
  topic_name = "topic2"
}]
}
```

Please let me know what I'm missing here. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried to rectify the issue with Terraform to create service bus topics that were occurring while running `terraform fmt` I was able to provision the requirement successfully.

The error you're seeing is related to the `terraform fmt` command, which ensures that Terraform configuration files are correctly formatted. The `fmt` command automatically updates configurations in the current directory for easy readability and consistency. If your Terraform code isn't formatted correctly, `terraform fmt` will fail.

The format seems correct in your provided code at first glance. However, sometimes minor issues like extra spaces, misaligned properties, or missing commas can trigger this error.

Initially, I tried adding one topic service bus queue and checking the format for the file structure and able to check the structure and I was also able to add new topics to the existing service bus.

**My terraform configuration:**

##### main.tf:

```
provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

resource "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = "demorg-vk"
  location = "West US"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_namespace" "example" {
  name                = "vksb-sbnamespace"
  location            = azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "Standard"
}

resource "azurerm_servicebus_topic" "example" {
  for_each = { for topic in var.servicebus_topics : topic.topic_name => topic }

  name         = each.value.topic_name
  namespace_id = azurerm_servicebus_namespace.example.id
  
}
```

##### variable.tf:

```
variable "servicebus_topics" {
  type = list(object({
    topic_name                              = string
    default_message_ttl                     = optional(string)
    max_size_in_megabytes                   = optional(number)
    requires_duplicate_detection            = optional(bool)
    duplicate_detection_history_time_window = optional(string)
    enable_batched_operations               = optional(bool)
    support_ordering                        = optional(bool)
    auto_delete_on_idle                     = optional(string)
    enable_partitioning                     = optional(bool)
    enable_express                          = optional(bool)
  }))
  description = "Topic details"
  default = [
    {
      topic_name = "topic1"
    }
    }
  ]
}
```

##### output.tf:

```
output "servicebus_topic_names" {
  value       = [for topic in azurerm_servicebus_topic.example : topic.name]
  description = "Names of the created service bus topics."
}
```

**Output:**

while running the desried `terraform fmt`

[image]

Then `terraform apply`

[image]

now I have tried to add one more topic to the service bus as mentioned below

##### variable.tf:

```
    {
      topic_name = "topic2"
    }
```

**output:**

now continue with the same commands mentioned above

**terraform fmt**
[image]

**terraform apply**

[image]

[image]